# Spring Batch MongoBatchItemWriter not flushing/committing to mongo

Tags: spring-batch

Starting to use Spring Batch for a new project.  I have a simple batch application (based off the Person sample) that has 4 jobs invoked in order.  The first 2 jobs delete all the elements of a mongo collection, the next Job is the Person job, and the 4th job manipulates the data loaded in Job #3.

Each Job has 1 step.  Each step has a unique MongoItemWriter.  It appears that the MongoItemWriters are not flushing to the mongodb until the application is finished, but not at the end of the step or job.

The job that loads the data from a flat file is this:

```
  @Bean
    @Qualifier("personWriter")
    public MongoItemWriter<Person> mongoItemWriter(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        return new MongoItemWriterBuilder<Person>().template(mongoTemplate)
                .collection("person")
                .build();
    }

    @Order(10)
    @Bean
    public Job importUserJob(PersonCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .flow(step1)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(@Qualifier("personWriter") MongoItemWriter<Person> writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("importUserStep")
                .<Person, Person>chunk(1)
                .reader(reader())
                .processor(processor())
                .writer(writer)
                .build();
    }
```

When the next job runs, that table is empty.

I expected that any of Chunk size=1, End of Step, or End of Job, would flush to mongo.
What am I missing?

Comment: I did not experience that from the sample here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples#mongodb-sample. How are you running these 4 jobs in sequence? Are you sure job 1 and 2 (those deleting data) are not re-executed? Please provide a minimal example that reproduces the issue to be able to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: So the issue was a bit of a rookie mistake.  I was reusing readers and writers.  Apparently, at least with readers, using the same reader in multiple jobs and/or steps will lead to unpredictable results.